# Typo3 how to get a <li> wrapped around an typolink link list

Tags: typo3

Hi I try to get the following out-put when including a .lib with

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.faqList"/>
```

in my fluid template. I get the links out put but not in the desired:

```
`<ul>
<li>
<a href="#" target="_blank">some text here</a>
</li>
</ul>
`
```

So this is the lib.faqList I tried to wrap in several ways but can not get it working also tried with {} and wrap stdWrap linkWrap etc. So how should thsi be done. I now get the ul and the links without the li?

```
    `## Linklist FAQ!!  [Begin]
lib.faqList = COA
lib.faqList{
wrap = <ul>|</ul> 

lib.faqList.10 = TEXT
lib.faqList.10.stdWrap = <li>|</li>
{lib.faqList.10.value = TYPO3 Association
lib.faqList.10.typolink.parameter = 29

}

lib.faqList.20 = TEXT
lib.faqList.20.stdWrap = <li>|</li>
{lib.faqList.20.value = TYPO3 Association
lib.faqList.20.typolink.parameter = http://association.typo3.org 
}

lib.faqList.30 = TEXT
lib.faqList.30.stdWrap = <li>|</li>
{lib.faqList.30.value = TYPO3 Association
lib.faqList.30.typolink.parameter = 27

}

lib.faqList.40 = TEXT
lib.faqList.40.stdWrap = <li>|</li>
{lib.faqList.40.value = TYPO3 Association
lib.faqList.40.typolink.parameter = 98

}


}

## Link list [End]
```

`

Comment: please verify what your active(!) typoscript is. like this it has multiple syntaxerrors. If in doubt go to TSOB and have a look what is recognized. After that you might correct your TS here and provide it with proper indention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch on you code, I see many bracet where they not belong...

```
## Linklist FAQ!!  [Begin]
lib.faqList = COA
lib.faqList {
    wrap = <ul>|</ul> 

    10 = TEXT
    10 {
        wrap = <li>|</li>
        value = TYPO3 Association
        typolink.parameter = 29
    }

    20 = TEXT
    20 {
        wrap = <li>|</li>
        value = TYPO3 Association
        typolink.parameter = http://association.typo3.org 
    }

    30 = TEXT
    30 {
        wrap = <li>|</li>
        value = TYPO3 Association
        typolink.parameter = 27
    }

    40 = TEXT
    40 {
        wrap = <li>|</li>
        value = TYPO3 Association
        typolink.parameter = 98
    }
}
## Link list [End]
```